# How to say the following phrase in Mandarin?

Tags: translation, mandarin

I'm preparing a presentation for my Mandarin class. The idea is to stage a situation. Basically the point is to create a situation which begins with a Chinese person asking for two foreigners to take a picture for him. Since the situation is to happen in China, this seems very unrealistic, so I decided to start the stage with the Chinese person talking to himself:

> I'd like to take a picture of me and my family, but there is no one around except those two foreigners. I will ask them.

How do I say that in Mandarin?

Comment: since everyone who has a smartphone can take selfie, this situation seems unrealistic. I input "I'd like to take a picture of me and my family, but there is no one around, execpt those two foreigners. I will ask them." in google translate, the result... 我想拍一张我和我的家人的照片，但是周围没有人，把这两个外国人都弄死了。 我会问他们。“ That is funny

Comment: except for "把这两个外国人都弄死了" the rest of translation seem fine

Comment: This guy doesn’t know how to take a selfie? Seems unlikely.

Comment: I find very plausible to ask someone to take a photo for you when it is a photo of you and your family. He's not taking a photo of hilmself only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I'd like to take a picture of me and my family, but there is no one around execpt those two foreigners. I will ask them."

我想找人帮我们拍一张全家福，但周围除了两个外国人就没有别人了。我去问问他们。

Answer (score 1):

This: '我想给我和我的家人拍照，但是这里除了那两个外国人没有别人了，我想让他们帮我。'

Comment: although 帮我做某事 seems quite common,帮我 w/o additional object less so, alternative suggestion: add
个忙: 帮我个忙  do me a favor

Comment: 帮我个忙 更接近口头语，不过你说得对